# Centering fabricjs object onclick?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I found another question with some code that worked for an earlier version of fabricjs but I have been struggling to make it work with 1.7.20. What am I doing wrong here? [If you go to this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/759FV/145/) you'll see it works when you toggle to 1.4 it works but anything further on breaks it.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text = new fabric.IText('Text', {
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
});
canvas.add(text);

document.getElementById('center').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  var leftcenter = canvas.width / 2
  var halfleft = obj.currentWidth / 2;
  obj.set("left", leftcenter - halfleft);
  obj.set("top", obj.get('top'));
  obj.setCoords();
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

---

```
<button id="center">Fit To left center</button>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just put it in a function and call the function onClick?

Comment: I have. Sorry, I accidentally pasted the same code where I meant to put my button. Fixed.

Comment: please answer your own question so it does not go unanswered

Comment: It's not solved, I merely updated it. I'm still experiencing the issue.

Comment: Ah, my apologies

Comment: I would suggest still trying an onClick rather than an eventListener

Comment: Okay I will give that a try

Comment: Tried adding a function [here](http://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/759FV/143/) without luck.

Comment: I don't see any function by the name of "test" in your JavaScript

Comment: Oops, my bad. [Here we go.](http://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/759FV/145/)

Comment: I am not on a computer now so I apologize I cannot assist further at this point. Try looking at your function, how it is written, and the calling of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `width` instead of `currentWidth` as there is no such property available in fabricjs. May be it was there in earlier versions and got removed later on.

var halfleft = (obj.width * obj.scaleX) / 2;

Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/759FV/148/